# How to show only 1 marker on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I have this weird problem with Google Maps V3 API. Showing multiple markers on a google map is fine, but when I only want to show a single marker on the map, I get no markers displaying?

The code below only shows a map with no markers.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);  

marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({  
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733),
    map: map
});
```

Adding a second marker shows 2 markers on the map.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);

marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({  
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733),
    map: map
}); 

marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({  
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733),
    map: map
});
```

So my question is, how do I only display a single marker on the map? Currently my workaround is to have 2 markers of the same lat/lng, but its not very elegant lol

Comment: looks correct. try declaring your markers with "var". my guess is you are overwriting marker1 in another function.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/wKMwR/

Comment: i was overwriting it. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code block totally works for me.  Here's the entire file I have where it's working, if this helps:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Map Test</title>
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 

<script>
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733);

    var options = {  
        zoom: 16,  
        center: latlng,  
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Map</h1>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%; width:100%;"></div>
<script>
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);

marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({  
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733),
    map: map
}); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

to display one marker on v3 google maps i did mine like this

```
function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // map view, can be set to satellite, street, roadview, aerialview
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title: "Uluru (Ayers Rock)"
            });

            marker.setMap(map);  
        }
```